# Necessary Camunda db tables for application to run

Tags: spring, spring-boot, camunda, pg-dump, pg-dumpall

I have a bash script that dumps globals and all schemas in cluster but dumps data only from 1 schema then imports the dump files in a new database inside a docker container.

Anything regarding Camunda is in a separate schema (not the one which data is getting dumped). My application uses Camunda and running the application against the cloned database is giving a lot of errors about Camunda. My question is what would be the solution here? I don't want to dump everything inside the Camunda schema. Is there any specific tables that are necessary to have filled?

It's a Spring boot 2.5 application with PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer top the [database schema documentation](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/user-guide/process-engine/database/database-schema/) to understand what different tables are used for and which dependencies exist.

I assume you definitely want to pick the

- ACT_ID tables (users, etc)
- ACT_RU tables (runtime information) and the
- ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY is also part of the engines runtime schema

If you disable [history](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/user-guide/process-engine/history/), you may not need ACT_HI tables. If you cannot disable history, then you may also need those because processes in the runtime also get written to the history. To reduce what you need to carry over, you can can set a low history time to live (TTL) and perform a history table [cleanup](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/webapps/cockpit/cleanup/).

It would be good to understand why you are doing this and why taking the complete schema after a cleanup is not a viable option. It would be the safest approach.